# Some questions on an integral inequality

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $a > 0$, let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $\mathcal{L}^1$ measurable, and suppose that $f$ isn't identically zero. Then use Holder's inequality to show that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f^2} {\sqrt{a^2 + x^2}} \leq C\|f\|_{3}^2$$ where $C > 0$ depends only on $a$. What is the minimum constant $C$ that satisfies this inequality?

Here I am using the Lebesgue measure.

Since I must use Holder's inequality, it should be possible to split up the integrand such that I have one function which is a member of $\mathcal{L}^p$ and another which is a member of $\mathcal{L}^q$, where $p$ and $q$ are Holder conjugates. However, it isn't obvious to me how to choose the functions.

Also, because I don't know how to prove that the integral is bounded above, I'm not sure how to find the minimal constant $C$. Some help or hints on both fronts would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $1=(3/2)^{-1}+3^{-1}$. Find two functions $a,b$ such that $ab$ is your integrand, $a^{3/2}$ and $b^3$ are integrable and one of them involves $f^3$.

Comment: I am very close, because I managed to pick $1 \over (a^2 + x^2)$ for $a$ and $f$ for $b$. However, I don't know how to write this in such a way that I get the $\|f\|_{3}^2$ term.

Comment: $ab$ is not your integrand then, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Holder's inequality with conjugate exponents $\frac 3 2$ and $3$ we have $\int \frac {f^{2}} {\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}\, dx \leq (\int (f^{2})^{3/2} dx) ^{2/3} (\int (\sqrt {a^{2}+x^{2}}) ^{-3}\, dx) ^{1/3}$ and $\int (f^{2})^{3/2} dx) ^{2/3} =\|f\|_3^{2}$. Take $C=(\int (\sqrt {a^{2}+x^{2}}) ^{-3}\, dx) ^{1/3}$ which is finite.

Comment: Thanks! Minimizing $C$ should be fairly easy.