# Finiteness of an integral if the function space changes

Tags: functional-analysis

In a [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043808/some-questions-on-an-integral-inequality/3043860#3043860) post, I asked about the finiteness of $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f^2} {\sqrt{a^2 + x^2}}$$ if $a > 0$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{L}^1$ measurable. I was wondering if this was still true if $f \in \mathcal{L^2(\mathbb{R}})$ or $f \in \mathcal{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}})$.

It seems to be true in the former case: by Holder's the integral should be bounded above by a finite number because $|f|^2$ is summable and the integral of the denominator is a finite number, so the upper bound (which is just the product) is also finite.

But what about the latter case? Can I use a similar line of reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f \equiv 1 \in \mathcal{L}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

$\frac{1} {\sqrt{a^2 + x^2}} \sim \frac 1 x$ when $x \to \infty$.

What can you conclude ?

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't try that trivial example. In this case you just come out with infinity. Thanks!